# How to print a prn file using QT?

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a ".prn" file and i want to print the same in my locally connected printer. How can i send the ".prn" file to the printer? How can i achieve this using QT?

Comment: I guess you are not aiming for linux pcs right? because there it would be enough to map QFile to /dev/lp0 and them simply stream the prn file to there.

Comment: Yes you are right. My target is on windows. In windows how can i map the file? can u give a brief description about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add wait for finished after execution of start

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString program = "cmd.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "/K";
arguments << QString("COPY /B %1 %2").arg(prnfilename,printername);
process->start(program, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it for windows - this is only a wild guessing...
simply use a QPrintDialog to get the desired printer name and hopefully you know the name of the prn file, then you do something like this:

```
QProcess    proc;
QStringList args = QStringList() 
    << "/K" 
    << QString("COPY /B %1 %2" ).arg(prn-filename).arg( printername );
proc.start( "cmd.exe", args );
```

this should work because you can print png on a cmd shell afaik via:

```
COPY /B full-filepath.prn \\PC-Name\Printer-Name
```

I hope this works/helps